# can C++ make_shared be used on arrays?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Converting this to a shared ptr is easy:

```
MyObject * myObject = new MyObject( int n );
auto myObject = make_shared<MyObject>( n );
```

But what if my code is an array?

```
char * myChars = new char[n];
auto myChars = make_shared<char>????
```

I want the resulting pointer to point to an array which calls the default dtor on each element when it goes out of scope. Is that possible?

Comment: To begin with, use a `vector`...

Comment: 4% related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16596950/560648

Comment: http://ideone.com/UcPk3G

Answer (score 1):

Well, likely, in C++11 you *may* use shared_ptr on arrays, but only if you manually provide appropriate deleter. Unlike unique_ptr which explicitly has partial specialization on T[], shared_ptr doesn't have one, but it may be supplied with a custom deleter.