# Why can't I make a unique pointer to an array, when I can make a shared pointer?

Tags: c++, c++17

The following is invalid:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
typedef double zip[10];

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<zip> s = std::make_unique<zip>();
    (*s)[0] = 2.0;
    std::cout << (*s)[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But the following is perfectly valid:

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<zip> s = std::make_shared<zip>();
    (*s)[0] = 2.0;
    std::cout << (*s)[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why the discrepancy? What am I missing?

Comment: Not what you asked, but the proper syntax for a `unique_ptr` to a `double[10]` would be `auto s = std::make_unique<double[]>(10);`.

Comment: Your first code would also work fine with `typedef std::array<double, 10> zip;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is because `shared_ptr` may or may not point to an array. Any particular `shared_ptr<T>` instance might point to a single `T` or to an array of `T`.

By contrast, `unique_ptr<T>` always points to a single `T`, while `unique_ptr<T[]>` points to an array of `T`. It's coded directly in the type itself. So the version that stores arrays has an appropriate `operator[]` overload, while the other does not.

It should also be noted that `shared_ptr::operator[]` is a C++17 addition, wheras `unique_ptr<T[]>::operator[]` has always been there.

Comment: If it's 17, then the second example is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Because `make_unique` on array of known bound is disallowed. See 
[Why is `make_unique<T[N]>` disallowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596950/why-is-make-uniquetn-disallowed)
and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique

Comment: You mean "*unknown*", not "*known*".

Comment: no, really "known". `make_unique<T[]>` is OK but `make_unique<T[n]>` is not OK. See the referred StackOverflow question.

Comment: @AdrianTam: The OP is asking about why you can't use `operator[]` on a `unique_ptr<T>`. That has nothing to do with `make_unique`.